# How to extend the functionality of standard convolution operator which is provided by tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I want to extend the functionality of Conv2D operator to support binary weights in tensorflow framework. Firstly, I modify the tensorflow/core/ops/nn_ops.cc, and add a new attribute to REGISTER_OP("Conv2D") which can be used to indicate whether to use binary weights in convolution computation:

```
REGISTER_OP("Conv2D")
    .Input("input: T")
    .Input("filter: T")
    .Output("output: T")
    .Attr("T: {half, bfloat16, float, double}")
    .Attr("strides: list(int)")
    .Attr("use_cudnn_on_gpu: bool = true")
    .Attr(GetPaddingAttrString())
    .Attr(GetConvnetDataFormatAttrString())
    .Attr("dilations: list(int) = [1, 1, 1, 1]")
    .SetShapeFn(shape_inference::Conv2DShape)
    .Attr("use_binary_weight: bool = true");
```

Then I modify the tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_ops.cc, add a new private bool member named use_binary_weight_ to Conv2DOp class. And furthermore, set a appropriate value to use_binary_weight_ in Conv2DOp constructor:

```
OP_REQUIRES_OK(context, context->GetAttr("use_binary_weight", &use_binary_weights_));
```

Finally, I transform full precision weights to binary weights at the beginning of Conv2DOp::Compute() when use_binary_weight_ equals to true.
At this point, the forward process of binary convolution is completed.

Now the problem is coming. Since this is a binary convolution, its gradient computation has a little difference from standard convolution. Therefore, Conv2DBackpropInput and Conv2DBackpropFilter operators need some special processes to support binary convolution. However, how do Conv2DBackpropInput and Conv2DBackpropFilter know whether to use binary convolution because they are not created explicitly in the train script.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you considered implementing this as a new distinct op? There is [a guide for it](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op), you wouldn't need to modify the original TF code (but rather extend it through a new library) and you can register the gradient function as you need it. In any case, the original gradient functions for convolution are defined and registered in [`tensorflow/python/ops/nn_grad.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_grad.py), you should be able to tweak that to your needs...